# When is it safe to save state in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have a react component that updates state from a form.

```
class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      someCheckboxState: false,
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <input onChange={this.handleChange} checked={this.state.someCheckboxState} />
    );
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      someCheckboxState: event.target.checked,
    });
  }
}
```

Now I want to send that state to the server (or somewhere). If I just do this

```
handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({
    someCheckboxState: event.target.checked,
  });
  SendStateToServer(JSON.stringify(this.state)); // BAD! Not yet mutated
}
```

I could put it in `render` but then it will get sent to the server on initial render as well as well and it seems silly to send state a function called `render`.

When is it okay to persist/serialize the state?

Comment: second parameter for setState is a callback that runs after the state change is complete

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The second argument of React's `setState` is a callback that is fired after the state transition is complete.

```
this.setState(newState, () => console.log(this.state));
```

So, in your case:

```
handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({
    someCheckboxState: event.target.checked,
  }, () => {
    SendStateToServer(JSON.stringify(this.state));
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `setState()` [second parameter](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate), perfect way to do such things.

```js
class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      someCheckboxState: false,
    }
  }
  render() {
    return ( < input type = "checkbox"
      onChange = {
        this.handleChange
      }
      checked = {
        this.state.someCheckboxState
      }
      />
    );
  }
  handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({
    someCheckboxState: event.target.checked,
  }, () => { // do your work
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state));
    });
}
}

ReactDOM.render( < Form / > , document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```