# ReactJS : Does this.setState have its effect immediately?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm wondering if `this.setState` changes states immediately, because it doesn't seem to do so.

To illustrate, let's assume that there is a checkbox....

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    switch: false
  };
  this.switch = this.switch.bind(this);
}

clickCoverSwitch(){
  console.log("Before clicking - ", this.state.switch);
  this.setState({switch: !this.state.switch});
  console.log("Now, the state is - ", this.state.switch);
}

render() {
    return (
       <input onClick={this.clickCoverSwitch} defaultChecked={this.state.coverSwitch} type="checkbox">
       </input>
    );
}
```

In this example, the checkbox is off by default - which is OK.

However, when the switch (i.e. checkbox) is clicked, I see the following messages in the console.

`Before clicking - false`

`Now, the state is - false`

The second line is supposed to show `true`, because `this.state.switch` should have been changed through `this.setState({switch:  !this.state.switch})`.

I'm not sure how I should interpret this.
Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: No, it's asynchronous. If you want to log the state after setting it you can use `setState`'s callback: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40641998/when-is-it-safe-to-save-state-in-react/40642027#40642027

Comment: True, partially. `setState` might be synchronous as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.

When altering state based on previous state values its better to use this syntax:

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({ switch: !prevState.switch}));
```

This way if there are multiple pending state changes, they wont overwrite each other:

```
//This way leads to undesirable results
Somefunction() {
  this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 3})
  this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 5})
}
//this.state.counter === 5 here

betterfunction() {
  this.setState((prevState) => ({ counter: prevState.counter + 3}))
  this.setState((prevState) => ({ counter: prevState.counter + 5}))
}
//The second setState will change based on the first one's values instead of overwritting them
//this.state.counter === 8 here
```

More info here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Answer (score 4):

Well, it depends... React's `setState` may be sync and async as well. Trigger context matters - more on this [topic here](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2893-setstate-state-mutation-operation-may-be-synchronous-in-reactjs.htm)

General rule - do not rely on `setState` being synchronous. If you need to perform operation when states propagates, use `setState` completion callback (second param passed to `setState`).

Comment: You can write the callback like this - 

this.setState({switch: !this.state.switch},console.log("Now, the state is - ", this.state.switch));

Comment: Are you sure? You are passing return value from `console.log("Now, the state is - ", this.state.switch)` call as "callback" value for `setState`

Comment: What Andreyco said. The safest bet is to just use a callback, but if you're wanting to do multiple subsequent state changes then you could look into when it's sync and when it's async